# Laravel 8 resource controller not fetching model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In Laravel 7 fetching a model was pretty straightforward, i just needed to setup mi resource route and make a get to the address:

http://localhost/test/public/employee/1

But i cant make it work on Laravel 8, according to my understanding i just need to do this:

```
public function show(Employee $employee)
{
    dd($employee);
}
```

But dd only returns an empty class:

[image: dd result]

If i do this:

```
public function show(Employee $employee)
{
    dd(Employee::find(1));
}
```

dd returns the correct data:

[image: dd correct]

```
Route::resources([
    'employee' => EmployeeController::class,
]);
```

Can somebody help me find what am i missing?

Regards...

Comment: Could you add the definition for this route to your question.

Comment: can you share your route?

Comment: Add the code how you defined Route.

Comment: my route is a resource route -> Route::resources(['employee' => EmployeeController::class,]);

Comment: What is the output of php artisan route:list then? (You could also do php artisan route:list | grep employee)

Comment: I am having the same problem. did you solve this?

Comment: @jeesoon yes, my error was that i was setting up the route names in my native language (spanish) and because of that the controller also fetched the model using the spanish verb, so i needed to change the parameter on the controller to receive the correct model (more info below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that i was naming the routes in spanish:

```php
Route::apiResource('empleados', EmployeeController::class);
```

And because of this Laravel is expecting to receive the model encapsulated in a spanish verb class (empleados instead of employee), So i needed to rename the parameter inside the method controllers to receive the correct model:

```php
    public function show(Employee $empleado)
    {
        return $empleado;
    }
```

Comment: I just found out that the routes URI ex. /abcemployee/{abcemployee} should be similar to resource controller ex. public function show(ABCEmployee $abcemployee), in my case i try to use php artisan make:model ABCEmployee -cmr the output of resource controller would be public function show(ABCEmployee $aBCEmployee) which doesnt work, my solution is to change the $aBCEmployee to $abcemployee

Answer (score 0):

Your Route must have the same variable like

```
Route::get('/employee/{employee}', 'EmployeeController@show');
```

And ensure you have binding middleware enabled for this route. `->middleware(['bindings']);`

Updating for Resource routing:

```
Route::resource('/employee', 'EmployeeController')->middleware('bindings');
```

Comment: my route is a resource route -> Route::resources(['employee' => EmployeeController::class,]);

Comment: `resource` and `get` are different route methods.

Comment: The bindings middleware will work for both route methods. PHP artisan route:list command will show you what variable name you will have to set on controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('employee', EmployeeController::class);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#resource-controllers